# How to prove that $\pi^{e^{\pi^e}}<e^{\pi^{e^{\pi}}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I have a question: I Can to proof that $\pi^e<e^{\pi}$ (it is easy), and also I proof that $\pi^{e^{\pi}}>e^{{\pi^e}}$ (by contradiction I assume that $\pi^{e^{\pi}}\leq e^{^{\pi^e}}$ and via natural logaritms obtains that $e^{\pi}<e^{\pi}\cdot \ln \pi <\pi^e$, an absurd whit the above inequality!)

But, the question is that I can not prove that $\pi^{e^{\pi^e}}<e^{\pi^{e^{\pi}}}$.

Any help!

Thanks!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859841/is-this-inequality-provable-e-left-pie-pi-e-pi-right

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help!

Comment: I saw @BarryCipra pointed you to another source whilst typing this up; hopefully you might find merit in this which uses properties of generic functions, rather than computations using logarithms. Not saying either is better, just different!