# about transcendental and algebraic numbers.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

a few days ago I asked about comparing numbers $e^{\pi^e}$ and $\pi^{e^{\pi}}$, etc. You can see in

[How to prove that $\pi^{e^{\pi^e}}<e^{\pi^{e^{\pi}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603931/how-to-prove-that-pie-piee-pie-pi)

Now, does anyone know of any result about the transcendence or not of the said numbers?

Comment: I would be very surprised if they were not transcendental.

Comment: I too, but it would be an arduous task, if not impossible, to prove its transcendences